# Determining an arrays value depending on another array

Tags: java

I'm currently working on one of my assignments, and am looking for some help with the logic for one of my functions.

First off I have a array of numbers to be categorized, then a number interval, this number determines in which position each of the numbers being plotted goes into array2.

ie.

```
int interval = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if((array1[i] > 0) && (array1[i] < interval)) {
        array2[0]++;
    }
}
```

However, the number from array1 is 3. I would then need another if statement like so:

```
...
}else if((array1[i] > 2) && (array1[i] < interval * 2)) {
    array2[1]++;
}else if((array1[i] >
```

As you can start to see the problem with this is that I would need to continue for an infinite range of numbers. So my question is what is an easier way of achieving this goal? Or is there already a library which I can utilize to do so?

I'm sorry if I didn't make this clear enough, also I would prefer if code wasn't given to me. I would appreciate if someone would be able to tell me a more effective way about going about this, thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Assuming that the interval is set to 2, and the numbers from array1 are between 0 and 10, I would need to create a code that would do such:

```
2 < numFromArray1 > 0 == array2[0]++
4 < numFromArray1 > 2 == array2[1]++
6 < numFromArray1 > 4 == array2[2]++
8 < numFromArray1 > 6 == array2[3]++
10 < numFromArray1 > 8 == array2[4]++
```

However, the numbers from array1 can be positive or negative, whole or decimal.

Comment: How large your number `number` can be. And also you are losing the condition: - `array1[i] == interval`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you post a more detailed explanation? Give a sample run? Also, what is 'number number'?

Comment: I ment to say this:

array1 = Set of numbers to be categorized

number = 3 would be a random number taken from array1

Comment: it seems too difficult to implement here. But is possible.

Comment: @user1327636 you need to make the pattern clear. From your two cases, the pattern is very ambiguous. Could be arithmetic progression, geometric progression or even something completely random. Give at least five `else if` blocks following the `if` block, in order of dealing with increasing number value.

Comment: I have added another example at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: what would happen with exactly the number 4? what would happen with negtive numbers?

Comment: @user1327636 See my answer for a way to do this without an unnecessary inner loop. Also, jlordo is right, my solution will discard exactly 4, exactly 6, etc. You could avoid that by deciding which category it should go to and then changing the correct condition from > or < to >= or <= respectively.

Comment: @user1327636 I have done the final touches on my answer. You can do this in **three** simple lines! You don't even need to have that `if` condition now, plus it solves the problem of exact numbers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question correct, and the interval would be 3, than occurrences of 0, 1 and 2 would increase array2[0], occurences of 3, 4 and 5 would increase array2[1] and so on, this would be a solution:

**EDIT** sorry, you did not want to see code. I can repost it, if you want. Think about a real easy way to determine which category a number will be in. I'll try to give a hint.

Interval = 3;

0,1,2 -> category 0

3,4,5 -> category 1

6,7,8 -> category 2

Once you know the category, it is easy to increment the desired number in array2.

It would look something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    int category = // determine category here
    // increase correct position of array2
}
```

After some dicussion, here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    int category = array1[i] / interval;
    array2[category]++;
}
```

My solution won't work for negative numbers. Also it is not specified how to handle them

Comment: I think I've figured it out with your method, correct me if I'm wrong. 

If the interval size is 2, and I have an array of numbers from 1-10. I would do something like:

array1[i] / interval = category - 1;

Comment: I think you mean `category = array1[i] / interval;` And why do you subtract 1? Other than that, this is it, please also post your final code for us to look at, and accept my answer if it really helped ;)

Comment: That's what I had ment, I just didn't bother to right it as a proper code.

I would subtract by one because that would give the proper category as arrays start off at the 0th element, not the first. So, assuming like in my previous examples with an interval of two and numbers from 1-10

    1/2 = 0.5 == Category 0
    2/2 = 1   == Category 0
    3/2 = 1.5 == Category 1

Because category 0 would be a number when divided by the interval would equal to between 0 and 1, category 1 would be any number when divided is between 1 and 2.

Comment: @jlordo. Your category range is not what OP is looking for. See the Original Post. He has posted the range. You might edit your post.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: I read "2 < numFromArray1 > 0 == array2[0]++"  as increment array2[0] if numFromArray1 is less than two and greater (or equals) as zero. Also read OPs comments on my solution, seems to be the right direction.

Comment: @jlordo. What about this condition: - `4 < numFromArray1 > 2 == array2[1]++` ?? Does it match? You have included `5` into this.

Comment: @user 1/2 = 0.5, in Java 1/2 (both are ints) is 0, so subtracting 1 would result in -1 which would obviously lead to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Also in Java 3/2 is 1, exactly the index you want..

Comment: @Rohit, in my example Inteval is 3 ;) as stated 1 line above

Comment: @jlordo. Ah! Sorry Sorry. Didn't see that. :(

Comment: You're right, I've coded a small sample for it but I'm getting an error, as 2 / interval (2) = 1 and it increments array2[1], when it's supposed to increment array2[0]. How would I go about setting is so that it would increment the correct category? (Feel free to post the code here now if you please.)

Comment: first a question: is my example correct? if your interval is 2, do you want to have 2 in category 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, your example is correct so far. Two would be in category 0.

Answer (score 7):

Use a nested loop. Obviously it's not infinitely many possibilities for interval because array2 has a fixed size. So if you loop through all the cells in array2, and then do some math to figure out what your conditions need to be... I won't give complete code (you asked me not to, but it would look something like:

```
for ( ... ) {
    for ( ... ) { 
        if (array1[i] > /* do some math here */ && ... ) {
            array2[/* figure out what this should be too */]++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Hopefully you can figure it out from this.

By the way, if you aren't required to use an array for array2, consider learning about `LinkedList<?>`for a data structure that can grow in size as you need it to.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/143089-linked-list-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

**Here's what you can do to consider all cases: -**

- First find out what is the **maximum value** in your array: - `array1`.
- Your range should be `0 to maxValueInArray1`
- Then inside your outer for loop, you can have another, that will run from `0` to the `(maximum value) / 2`. Because, you don't want to check for `maximum value * 2` in your `interval`
- And then for each value, you can check for the range, if it is in that range, use `array2[j]`

For E.G: -

```
for (...) // Outer loop {
    for (int j = 0; j <= maximumValueinArray1 / 2; j++) {
        // Make a range for each `j`
        // use the `array2[j]` to put value in appropriate range.
    }
}
```

In your inner loop, you might check for this condition, based on following reasoning: -

For `interval = 2`, and say `maximumValueinArray1` is `max`, your range looks like: -

```
  0 * interval ----- (1 * interval)  --> in `array2[0]` (0 to 2)
  1 * interval ----- (2 * interval)  --> in `array2[1]` (2 to 4)
  2 * interval ----- (3 * interval)  --> in `array2[2]` (4 to 6)

and so on.

 ((max / 2) - 1) * interval ----- (max / 2) * interval  (`max - 2` to max)
```

**So, try relating these conditions**, with the inner loop I posted, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @user1327636.. Take a look at the answer. I think you will get an idea of what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but from your code snippets, I can come up with this inner `for` loop:

```
//OUTDATED CODE - please see code block in EDIT below
//for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
//    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) { //or Integer.MAXVALUE or whatever
//        if ((array1[i] > (j*2)) && (array1[i] < interval * ((j*2)==0?2:(j*2)) )) {
//            array2[j]++;
//        }
//    }
//}
```

**EDIT:** Owing to your recent edit, this is more suitable and you don't have to run an inner loop!:

1. Loop through array1
2. For each element in array1, find array2 index by taking floor of element / interval
3. Add 1 to array2 element at found index.

DON'T LOOK AT THE CODE BELOW =)

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    int index = Math.floor(array1[i] / interval);
    array2[index]++;

    //the rest are actually not necessary as you just need to get the index
    //and the element will be within range, left inclusive (lower <= value < upper)

    //int lower_range = Math.floor(array1[i] / interval) * interval;
    //    //or int lower_range = index * interval;
    //int upper_range = Math.ceil(array1[i] / interval) * interval;

    //if ((array1[i] > lower_range) && (array1[i] < upper_range)) {
    //    array2[index]++;
    //}
}
```

Comment: Yea didn't notice :( Well my code could be wrong since his snippets aren't clear of what the math part should be. He only gave 2 cases and it's very hard to judge the pattern from it.

Comment: Also, your conditions are not correct. You should multiply your j with interval rather than 2.

Comment: As I said before, the question doesn't make it clear what the pattern is. I was making a guess at the pattern. You're probably right but the original asker will have to confirm.

Comment: @ADTC. `I would prefer if code wasn't given to me.` -> This is what OP wrote somewhere in the post.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm just too used to churning out code than writing documentation :P

Comment: @ADTC. There is nothing wrong in giving out code, till you explain properly what your code is doing. Specially when you are giving them to beginners. Just saying that `try this code` does not help.

Comment: @ADTC That's almost exactly my answer. Also `Math.floor()` returns a double, which you can't assign to an int ;)

Comment: Yea haha, you beat me to it. Yea I know there would be casting problems. I'm just writing this code from the top of my head. Not testing it out. Please feel free to edit and add casts :)

Comment: I just assumed it to be ints, so it would floor by itself ;) The Logic wouldn't change, you and me would just have to handle floating point numbers different

Comment: I'm not sure how simple division of integers handle floating points. But it's best not to take the risk, and use a surefire method like Math.floor or Math.ceil.

Answer (score 0):

The relationships and pattern are hard to figure out. My attempt in interpreting what you want:

How about something like:

```
if ( array1[i] < interval * (interval - 2) ) {
    array2[interval-2]++;
}
```

Comment: what if your condition fails? which element in array2 would you increment?